# ASP.NET MVC 5 Web API Help Pages Not Showing XML Sample when UseXmlSerializer = true

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 with WebAPI application just doing a straight return GetProducts() which returns `IEnumerable<Product>`.

Both JSON and XML Serialization works fine using the defaults and the API Help Pages showed a sample for both types. However when I change the default XML Formatter in the Global.asax.cs file to

```
var xml = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter;
xml.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

the API Help Pages now no longer display the XML Sample, just the JSON sample under the Response Formats.

I tried adding `config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;` to the `HelpPageConfig` but it didn't make any difference.

Does anyone have any ideas why the Xml sample output disappears?

Comment: try to write your `global.asax` code to `WebApiconfig.cs`

Comment: @Nilesh I tried adding config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true; to the WebApiConfig.cs file but unfortunately it didn't make any difference

Comment: Do you see any error message displayed when you switch to XmlSerializer? If yes, then you would need to see if in fact your service is working with XmlSerializer..that is, you can try making an actual request to see if the object is getting serialized using the new xml serializer setting

Comment: Hi @KiranChalla I don't actually see an error message but yes I have come to the conclusion that it must be a problem with the serialization. It must be failing. I have decided in the end to just not use the XmlSerializer. It is just causing more hassle than it is worth.

Comment: I had this problem because my DataContract attribute specifies an empty name and namespace : [DataContract(Name = "", Namespace = "")]. I simply removed the Name and Namespace values.